# left join and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, left-join

I have table like below two, I want to list location row base on been used in task table, and dont duplicate location.id, also order by column in task table.

I'm not sure how to solve it use group by or other method?
(I also check distinct before, but it limit select specific column, seems not what I want..)
how to solve it ?

```
location
id | status | ...
1  | ...
2  | ...

id SERIAL NOT NULL

task
id | location_id | create_date | start_date | ...
1  | 1           | ...
2  | 1           | ...
3  | 2           | ...

id SERIAL NOT NULL
location_id integer DEFAULT NULL
create_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL  
start_date date NOT NULL
```

need output result

```
location  order by task.create_date
id | ...
1  | ...
2  | ...
```

query

I add select t.location_id it works to count, but I still have problem in select rows

count works

```
SELECT count(l.*)
   AS total_row_count 
   FROM location l
         LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT t.location_id
           FROM task t
           GROUP BY t.location_id
           ) t ON t.location_id  = l.id
        WHERE l.status = ANY($1::int[])
```

select

```
SELECT
  l.* 
  FROM location l 
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT t.location_id, t.create_date
          FROM task t
          GROUP BY t.location_id
          ) t ON t.location_id  = l.id
       WHERE l.status = ANY($1::int[]) 
       ORDER BY t.create_date desc NULLS LAST, 
       l.name asc NULLS LAST, l.id desc NULLS LAST OFFSET $2 LIMIT $3
```

error:

> column "t.create_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used
>   in an aggregate function SELECT t.create_date, t.location_id

Comment: I don't understand what result you're trying to get. Show it as a table like you did with your sample data.

Comment: please see my update, I want to get location table but not duplicate location rows

Comment: You sample data is incomplete. Can you provide the data in the relevant columns?

Comment: @user1775888 The sample output can be obtained by `select * from location`. Clearly you haven't provided a substantive example. If you want help, you need to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do a left join to get the location_id and corresponding number of rows in task table like this:

```
select l.id, count(t.location_id) times
from location l
left join task t
on l.id = t.location_id
group by l.id
order by max(t.create_date) desc;
```

If location_id is unique (probably PK) in your location table and you want to select all or more columns from that table, you can just put them in both the select and group by clause of the query.

Comment: thanks for reply, my problem is how to get rows? the t.create is not unique how to be use in group by ??  but I need it to use in order

Comment: Since you're aggregating over location_id, you need to order by aggregate of date (may be max or min like I used in my updated answer).

Comment: select l.location_id ?? or select l.id?  group by l.location_id ?? or l.id or t.location_id ?

Comment: @user1775888 Yes. `l.id`. Updated

Comment: I tried use this syntax to do count like this `SELECT count(l.*)
 AS total_row_count 
 FROM location l
       LEFT JOIN task t ON t.location_id = l.id WHERE l.status = ANY($1::int[])
       GROUP BY l.id` but it get all location rows, do I miss something

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list the records and columns of table `location` only then you can use `exists`, like shown below:

```
select * from location l where exists (select 1 from task where location_id=l.id)
```

You can find a demo [here](http://rextester.com/INLW84355).

Comment: thanks for reply, but I also want to order by column in task table

Comment: OK, well, you never mentioned anything about ordering in your question. How *do* you want to order your data then? You should - if possible - edit your original post accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but which `t.create_date` do you want to use, when there are several? First or last? @Gurv was assuming the latter in his answer.

Comment: oh !! I got it! I didn't realize that. min or max is ok to me, I want to know how to use group correctly

Comment: is correct syntax like this, fist left join , then group by l.id then use max or min in order by `SELECT
 l.* 
 FROM location l 
  LEFT JOIN task t ON t.location_id = l.id 
  WHERE l.status = ANY($1::int[])
  GROUP BY l.id
  ORDER BY 
    max(t.create_date) desc NULLS LAST, 
    l.name asc NULLS LAST, 
    l.id desc NULLS LAST OFFSET $2 LIMIT $3`